# AWS EC2 to Plot.ly

Tags: connection, graph-visualization, plotly, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find ways to connect AWS EC2 with plot.ly. I have checked both the documentation but couldn't find any tutorial.

My data files are kept on EC2 and I want to visualize them on plot.ly

Please could someone direct me in right direction ?

Comment: You might like the [dashboard tutorial](http://moderndata.plot.ly/create-a-plotly-dashboards-in-under-10-minutes/).

Comment: @Guus about 50+ files and will keep increasing ..I m now considering AWS S3